# The error in Submit Add button in PrimeFaces using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

My xhtml code is here when I press add button it is showing that TaxNumber is not valid for this value...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form enctype="multipart-data">
        <f:view>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <f:facet name="header">

Add Employee
</f:facet>
                <p:outputLabel value="Employee Id:" />
                <p:inputText id="employeeId" required="true"
                    value="#{employeeBean.employeeId}" 
                             label="Employee Id"
                    validator="#{employeeBean.validateEmployeeId}" />

                </p:inputText>
    <p:outputLabel value="Country Name" />


        <p:selectOneMenu id="countryName" required="true"
                value="#{employeeBean.countryName}" label="Country">
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.allCountryName}" />
                <f:ajax event="change" render="stateName eTaxType " />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:outputLabel value="State Name" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="stateName" required="true"
                value="#{employeeBean.stateName}" label="State">
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.allStateName}" />
                <f:ajax event="change" render="city" />

            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="City:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.cityName}" id="city"
                required="true" label="City">
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.allCityNames}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Employee Street Address:" />
            <p:inputTextarea value="#{employeeBean.employeeStreetAddress}"
                id="estreetAddress" required="true" maxlength="255"
                label="Employee Street Address"
                validator="#{companyBean.validateClientAddress}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Zip code" />
            <p:inputText value="#{employeeBean.zipcode}" id="ezipcode"
                required="true" maxlength="20" label="Zip code for streetAdress" />



            <p:outputLabel value="Week ending Date" />
            <p:calendar value="#{employeeBean.weekEndingDate}"
                id="weekEndingDate">
            </p:calendar>




            <p:outputLabel value="Tax Identification Number:*" />
            <p:panelGrid columns="1" id="taxNum">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.taxIdentificationType}"
                    id="eTaxType" label="TaxNumber">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.taxTypeBycountryName}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:inputText value="#{employeeBean.taxIdentificationNumber}"
                    id="eTaxNum" required="true" label="Tax Identification Number" />
            </p:panelGrid>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Add" ajax="false"
                    action="#{employeeBean.addEmployee}">

                </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </f:view>
</h:form>
```

There is Backing Bean which is look like this.. when the submit (Add button) is pressed no Add method Called,I have tried a lot but it is not working,Although without ajax is working  fine but our business requirement is that the TaxType should be auto-populated according Country like PAN-Number....I have already spent two-three days.

```
employeeDto.setWeekEndingDate(getWeekEndingDate());
    employeeDto.setEmployeeStreetAddress(getEmployeeStreetAddress());
    employeeDto.setEmployeeHourlySalaryRate(getEmployeeHourlySalaryRate());
    employeeDto.setZipcode(getZipcode());
    employeeDto.setFileUploaded(getFileUploaded() + File.separator
            + getEmployeeId());
    employeeDto.setLeaveEntitled(leaveAssigned());
    employeeDto.setCompanyDTO(getCompanyService().getAllCompany().get(0));

    employeeDto.setCityDTO(getCityService().getCityById(getCityIdNameFromState()));


    getIemployeeService().addEmployee(employeeDto);
    System.out.println("Added employee");


TaxIdentificationCredentialsDTO tax1=new TaxIdentificationCredentialsDTO();
tax1.setIdentificationType(getTaxIdentificationType());
tax1.setIdentificationNumber(getTaxIdentificationNumber());
tax1.setEmployeeDto(employeeDto);
getTaxService().addTaxInformation(tax1);

    return "employee added successfully";
}
```

Comment: I don't undestand well your backing bean code. why it is returning a message?

Comment: also, please post ALL your backing bean

Comment: also, please provide what app server you're using and what primefaces version

Comment: My primefaces version is 3.5 and I am using tomcat server my method has return type string so I am just giving it "added successfully" and I am using Maven,I have tried with Primefaces 4.0 but result does not change.

Comment: @BalusC plz see this above problem I am facing with.

Comment: look, if you don't provide your backing bean, all I can do is guess.

Comment: Thank God it is working fine.I was stupid I have'nt watched it ,it was RequestScoped so It was not working.

Comment: @Leo Thanks a lot for giving your valuable time.Can you plz suggest some more useful link for jsf and primefaces because I am newbee for Jsf.

Comment: if you had posted your backing bean, we could have helped you :-) I think you can go well with jsf with [1] primefaces pdf [2] balusc blog and [3] some ibm jsf tutorials

Comment: please notice that if you use viewscoped, your backing bean must be serializable (that was not intuitive for me at the first time and it's well explained in balusc blog)